# Slicing a numpy array and passing the slice to a function

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, slice, reshape

I want to have a function that can operate on either a row or a column of a 2D ndarray. Assume the array has C order. The function changes values in the 2D data.

Inside the function I want to have identical index syntax whether it is called with a row or column. A row slice is [n,:] and column slice [:,n] so they have different shapes. Inside the function this requires different indexing expressions.

Is there a way to do this that does not require moving or allocating memory? I am under the impression that using reshape will force a copy to make the data to make it contiguous. Is there a way to use nditer in the function?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this:

```
In [74]: def foo(arr, n):
    ...:     arr += n
    ...:     
In [75]: arr = np.ones((2,3),int)
In [76]: foo(arr[0,:],1)
In [77]: arr
Out[77]: 
array([[2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1]])
In [78]: foo(arr[:,1],[100,200])
In [79]: arr
Out[79]: 
array([[  2, 102,   2],
       [  1, 201,   1]])
```

In the first case I'm adding `1` to one row of the array, ie. a row slice.  In the second case I'm add a array (list) to a column.  In that case `n` has to have the right length.

Usually we don't worry about whether the values are `C contiguous`.  Striding takes care of access either way.